# jQuery autocomplete tags plugin with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, tags

I am looking for good tags autocomplete plugin with Ajax. Currently i am working with http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ but i need to get data from ajax query not from json file. Is it even possible? All the plugins that i've seen got data from array in json file. I need to search data dynamically directly from the database. Something like stackoverflow tags input, i suppose.

Comment: Check out http://jqueryplugin.net/category/tags/

Comment: Nice one, but i didn't finde proper plugin :(

Answer (score 0):

Look into [jquery UI autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), especially the remote data source [example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).

You can directly specify a remote data source which returns data in either of the below formats like:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
  source: "search.php" // url to remote source
});
```

The [data source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) should return data in any of the following formats:

- An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
- An array of objects with label and value properties:

  ```
  [ { label:"Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but i need also to type tag that is not in tags db. Type and creat a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem. I used bootstrap-tagsinupt plugin, jquery get() function, also i used json_encode to parse the data from array.